# Trying to implement SSH automation

Tags: linux, python, automation, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have automated SSH login to the server using below script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
        set timeout 60
        set IPaddress "xxxx"
        set Username "xxxx"
        set Password "xxxxxx"

spawn  ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $Username@$IPaddress
        expect "*assword: "
        send "$Password\r"

        interact

exit
```

Now I have a scenario, Let me say that I have A, B, and C. A is the local server, and B and C are remote servers. Only using private network from B I can SSH into server C. I can access B from A and I am trying to automate SSH to C from server A using scripting.

- Cant use ssh key authentication :(

Comment: Your question is unclear, as I'm not sure what the script you've provided has to do with anything.  Can C communicate with A in any way?  Have you established that you can SSH to A form C without your automation?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: ssh port forwarding is probably the better solution. Having also certificates instead of password could help, but you need to be sure you are allowed to do it. If C is not accessible from external, probably the security is relaxed, so by bypassing it, you could cause huge problem on internal network.

Comment: Cant use ssh key authentication :(

Answer (score 0):

Draw a little diagram next time :-) As I understand you need to use an intermediate host to connect to a remote server. The intermediate machine is called a jump host. I have never done it myself but I know the concept.

Maybe you might start wiht tihs page from the [OpenSSH Cookbook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts)

Also please try to use key based authentication for automated login, if you cant at avoid it in the first place. Saveing passwords in clear text is very dangerous.

Comment: Yeah u are correct but I cant use ssh key and have to use the password